# retrieve events which has a specific class in fullcalendar

Tags: fullcalendar

I want to get client events which has only a specific class. I need to get event objects which has the particular class. I tried following two ways.

```
1. $('#calendar').fullCalendar('clientEvents',{className: 'class'}
2. $('#calendar').fullCalendar('clientEvents',{className: ['class']}
```

Did not work.

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to get the actual Event Object, or just the DOM element?
Perhaps a bit more information on what you are trying to do.

I assume you know you can just do this:

```
$('#calendar .class-you-want')
```

to get any DOM item that is inside the calendar.
if you have set the class inside the Event Object, then you should get all the 'a' link elements with that class.

Another option would be to use the

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('clientEvents');
```

which will return a list of all the events, you could then check for the event className
ex:

```
$.each( $('#calendar').fullCalendar('clientEvents'), function(index, event) {
    if( event.className == 'class-searched' ) { //do something }
});
```

inside full calendar setup:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({ ...
    eventRender: function(event, element, view) {
        element.attr('data-id', event.id);
        element.attr('data-SomeEventData', event.SomeEventData);
    }
});
```

your event data may look like this:

```
[{ 
    "id": "event1", 
    "title": "event title", 
    "start": "2014-12-29T09:00:00", 
    "SomeEventData": "special data you pass that calendar ignores but you add to the 'a' attribute" 
}]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I need actual Event objects. Should we use a loop to get this events objects ? Isn't there any other way to do this?

Comment: the 'even't object in my second part returns actual event objects. When you send event data, you can add attributes so that when you loop through in this way, you can find the ones you want.  I've not found a faster way to select specific events.  Another option would be to grab the events via JSON again and use them that way.

Comment: another thought: you can override the eventRender event, and add all sorts of great things to the event Element (via data-XXX tags). I've done this so that I can grab specific events and information quickly without looping (but don't need the entire event object).

Comment: Thank you very much for the comment. Can you add this comment as an answer with a simple example of how to use data-XXX tags.

Comment: updated @Charith to show adding the data tags to the events 'a' HTML element.